# Formatting localtime() in perl script

Tags: perl, date

Wondering how to format the output of localtime() to year/month/day

I was able to do it easily using the 'date' command from terminal but I need to calculate previous dates as well, which I've figured out how to do in perl.

```
foreach my $i (0..7)
{
  my $date = localtime(time() - 60*60*24*$i);
  print "$i day(s) ago: $date\n";
}
```

Prints out this :

```
0 day(s) ago: Tue Apr  3 12:01:13 2012
1 day(s) ago: Mon Apr  2 12:01:13 2012
2 day(s) ago: Sun Apr  1 12:01:13 2012
3 day(s) ago: Sat Mar 31 12:01:13 2012
4 day(s) ago: Fri Mar 30 12:01:13 2012
5 day(s) ago: Thu Mar 29 12:01:13 2012
6 day(s) ago: Wed Mar 28 12:01:13 2012
7 day(s) ago: Tue Mar 27 12:01:13 2012
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

foreach my $i (0..7)
{
  my ($d, $m, $y) = (localtime(time() - 60*60*24*$i))[3,4,5];
  printf "%d day(s) ago: %d/%d/%d\n", $i, $y+1900, $m+1, $d;
}
```

***Output:***

```
0 day(s) ago: 2012/4/3
1 day(s) ago: 2012/4/2
2 day(s) ago: 2012/4/1
3 day(s) ago: 2012/3/31
4 day(s) ago: 2012/3/30
5 day(s) ago: 2012/3/29
6 day(s) ago: 2012/3/28
7 day(s) ago: 2012/3/27
```

Comment: Don't do this sort of date math on your own, as explained in perlfaq4. Just ask TomTom how much that matters. :)

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example of [`POSIX::strftime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?POSIX#strftime):

```
use POSIX ();

my @local = ( localtime )[0..5];
foreach my $i ( 0..7 ) {
  my $date = POSIX::strftime( '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y', @local);
  print "$i day(s) ago: $date\n";
  $local[3]--;
}
```

Comment: That's a particularly clever way of doing that. :) Is the guaranteed to work everywhere? I couldn't find any documentation on what that should do.

Comment: @briandfoy, I don't know if it's completely portable, but the odd values are handled by `POSIX::mktime` and `POSIX::strftime` from 5.8 to 5.14 on Windows (Strawberry and Active), UNIX and Linux -- and everywhere I've tried it. So, I don't know about a *guarantee*.

Answer (score 6):

If you are doing date math, use a module that does it right. For instance, [DateTime](https://www.metacpan.org/module/DateTime):

```
use DateTime;

my $date = DateTime->now;

foreach my $i ( 0 .. 10 ) {
    $date->subtract( days => 1 );
    say $date->ymd( '/' );
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

you could use [POSIX::strftime](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=466503) from POSIX module.

`perl  -mPOSIX -e 'printf POSIX::strftime("%Y/%m/%d",localtime)`.